# "sh: heroku: command not found" in PyCharm CE

Tags: python, linux, heroku, pycharm

**SEE EDIT BELOW**

I have Heroku CLI properly installed but it is not accessible from the venv terminal in my PyCharm CE project.

My Heroku version is as follows:

```
$ heroku --version
 ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.60.1 to 7.60.2.
heroku/7.60.1 linux-x64 node-v14.19.0
```

Typing heroku in the PyCharm project terminal returns the following:

```
(venv) heroku
sh: heroku: command not found
```

I've done a search for "sh: heroku: command not found" + PyCharm on StackOverflow but I don't think this has been asked before.

Please advise. Thank you.

**EDIT**

Notes: I've tried adding Heroku (/snap/bin) to PATH and changed the PyCharm terminal shell as suggested by Naitik Mundra (Thanks BTW). Didn't work.

WORKAROUND: Just activate the venv and use the default terminal. Closing.

Comment: What shell are you using in the first example? Use `echo "$SHELL"` to find out. It might be that heroku is in PATH in zsh/bash(used n terminal emulator) but not sh. If this is the case, either change the shell in pycharm or add `heroku` to path.

Comment: I tried both methods - changing the shell in PyCharm and adding path. Still doesn't work. The workaround is using the default terminal directly. Thank you.

Comment: Can you please tell me what the ouput for `echo "$SHELL"` is?

Comment: /bin/sh (originally). Then /bin/bash after I tried your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

Answered. WORKAROUND: Just activate the venv and use the default terminal. Closing.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).